# Why does this return a Path::Class::Dir instead of a file?

Tags: perl

So I was using `File` for the type originally but for type validation was failing, so I switched it to `Dir`. However the final path is a file, so I'm not sure what it is that I'm doing wrong.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use namespace::autoclean;

# VERSION

use Moose::Role;

use MooseX::Types::Moose qw( Str );
use MooseX::Types::Path::Class qw( File Dir );
use File::ShareDir::PathClass;

has cybs_wsdl => (
    required  => 0,
    lazy      => 1,
    is        => 'ro',
    isa       => Dir,
    builder   => '_build_cybs_wsdl',
);

sub _build_cybs_wsdl {
        my $self = shift;


        my $wsdl = 'CyberSourceTransaction_1.62.wsdl';

        my $file
            = File::ShareDir::PathClass->dist_file(
                'Business-CyberSource',
                 $wsdl
            );

        return $file;
}
```

note: final path is this: `/home/ccushing/Business-CyberSource/.build/rzuQn5s899/blib/lib/auto/share/dist/Business-CyberSource/CyberSourceTransaction_1.62.wsdl`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bug in [File::ShareDir::PathClass](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aShareDir%3a%3aPathClass).

Patch:

```
-        return dir( $result );
+        return $sub =~ /_file\z/ ? file( $result ) : dir( $result );
```

Filed a [ticket](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=70660)

Comment: @xenoterracide, Fixed in 1.112440

Answer (score 2):

Because [File::ShareDir::PathClass](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aShareDir%3a%3aPathClass) isn't smart enough.  All it does is wrap the corresponding [File::ShareDir](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aShareDir) method in a `dir()`.  That doesn't work so well when the result is a file instead of a directory.

I'd drop File::ShareDir::PathClass and just use `file(dist_file(...))`.